# Catalyst InterVLAN Routing w/ Failover ASAs

Tags: routing, vlan, cisco-asa, layer3, failover

I currently have interVLAN routing configured on my Catalyst 3750. My gateway of last resort is my ASA firewall. The switch reaches the firewall through a layer 3 port. The port is configured as follows:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/24
no switchport
ip address 10.0.0.3 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
```

The ASA's IP address is 10.0.0.1, so the 0/0 route on the ASA is configured using 10.0.0.1 as the gateway.

I want to configure an active/standby failover ASA cluster. What is the best way to go about connecting the standby ASA to the Catalyst? I think that the standby ASA needs to be able to reach the Catalyst using the same IP (10.0.0.3) as the primary ASA. However, I cannot assign that IP to another port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is create a new VLAN with 10.0.0.3 as the SVI (VLAN) interface.  Eash ASA (in a failover pair) gets connected to an access port on that VLAN.